# Dynamo DB Optimistic Locking Behavior during Save Action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

Scenario: We have a Dynamo DB table supporting Optimistic Locking with Version Number. Two concurrent threads are trying to save two different entries with the same primary key value to that Table.

Question: Will ConditionalCheckFailedException be thrown for the latter save action?

Comment: please follow your question and ask subsequent queries. let me know if my answer solved your query ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second thread which tries to insert the same data would throw `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ConditionalCheckFailedException
```

As soon as the item is saved in database, the subsequent updates should have the version matching with the value on DynamoDB table (i.e. server side value).

> save — For a new item, the DynamoDBMapper assigns an initial version
>   number 1. If you retrieve an item, update one or more of its
>   properties and attempt to save the changes, the save operation
>   succeeds only if the version number on the client-side and the
>   server-side match. The DynamoDBMapper increments the version number
>   automatically.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar use case in past but in our case, multiple threads reading first from the dynamoDB and then trying to update the values.

So finally there will be change in version by the time they read and they try to update the document and if you don't read the latest value from the DynamoDB then intermediate update will be lost(which is known as update loss issue refer [aws-docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate%20aws-docs) for more info).

I am not sure, if you have this use-case or not but if you have simply 2 threads trying to update the value and then if one of them get different version while their request reached to DynamoDB then you will get `ConditionalCheckFailedException` exception.

More info about this error can be found here http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.michelboudreau/alternator/0.10.0/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/ConditionalCheckFailedException.java