# DynamoDB Concurrency Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm building a system in which many DynamoDB (NoSQL) tables all contain data and data in one table accesses data in another table.

Multiple processes are accessing the same item in a table at the same time. I want to ensure that all of the processes have updated data and aren't trying to access that item at the exact same time because they are all updating the item with different data.

I would love some suggestions on this as I am stuck right now and don't know what to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757608/dynamo-db-optimistic-locking-behavior-during-save-action/43758297#43758297 this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, AmitK! I will implement that and hopefully solve it.

Comment: Unrelated note: "many DynamoDB (NoSQL) tables all contain data and data in one table accesses data in another table". This implies a misuse of Dynamo tables as a sort of RDBMS "expandable relation". That's not a great use of NoSQL/DDB, and could get you in some trouble with scan costs and performance degradation over time. Consider at least some elements of single-table design.

Answer (score 0):

Optimistic locking is a strategy to ensure that the client-side item that you are updating (or deleting) is the same as the item in Amazon DynamoDB. If you use this strategy, your database writes are protected from being overwritten by the writes of others, and vice versa.

With optimistic locking, each item has an attribute that acts as a version number. If you retrieve an item from a table, the application records the version number of that item. You can update the item, but only if the version number on the server side has not changed. If there is a version mismatch, it means that someone else has modified the item before you did. The update attempt fails, because you have a stale version of the item. If this happens, you simply try again by retrieving the item and then trying to update it. Optimistic locking prevents you from accidentally overwriting changes that were made by others. It also prevents others from accidentally overwriting your changes.

To support optimistic locking, the AWS SDK for Java provides the @DynamoDBVersionAttribute annotation. In the mapping class for your table, you designate one property to store the version number, and mark it using this annotation. When you save an object, the corresponding item in the DynamoDB table will have an attribute that stores the version number. The DynamoDBMapper assigns a version number when you first save the object, and it automatically increments the version number each time you update the item. Your update or delete requests succeed only if the client-side object version matches the corresponding version number of the item in the DynamoDB table.

ConditionalCheckFailedException is thrown if:

You use optimistic locking with @DynamoDBVersionAttribute and the version value on the server is different from the value on the client side.

You specify your own conditional constraints while saving data by using DynamoDBMapper with DynamoDBSaveExpression and these constraints failed.

Note

DynamoDB global tables use a “last writer wins” reconciliation between concurrent updates. If you use global tables, last writer policy wins. So in this case, the locking strategy does not work as expected.

Comment: From AWS docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.htmlDynamoDB global tables use a “last writer wins” reconciliation between concurrent updates. If you use global tables, last writer policy wins. So in this case, the locking strategy does not work as expected.

Comment: But the question did not mention about global tables